# Remove dynamic component selector from DOM

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I am trying to create dynamic components using `containerRef.createComponent(this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent),index)`

This will create unnecessary html tag of the **child component selector** in the DOM. I have created a Directive to move the elements (including the comments for the ngContainer or other locationRefs) inside the ChildComponent outside of the selector and then delete the selector tag with the following logic.

```
        const parentElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        while (parentElement.lastChild) {
            const element = parentElement.lastChild;
            parentElement.removeChild(element);
            parentElement.parentNode.insertBefore(element, parentElement.nextSibling);
        }
        parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(parentElement);
```

The above logic works fine, however, the issue is that this logic is taking 5+ seconds on the page load since I am creating hundreds of child components (Reason for removing the selector in the first place). Is there a faster Way to create dynamic components without their selector in the DOM?

P.S: I have tried removing the selector from the child component's @Component decorator which creates ng-component tag instead.

EDIT:

1. In the angular source code for create method in ComponentFactory, I see the `const hostRNode`, which is the new tag for component selector, I am woking on a way to patch the componentFactory.create at runtime to remove the logic associated with the `hostRNode`. If I find success, I will add a solution here.

```
  create(
      injector: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][]|undefined, rootSelectorOrNode?: any,
      ngModule?: viewEngine_NgModuleRef<any>|undefined): viewEngine_ComponentRef<T> {
    ngModule = ngModule || this.ngModule;

    const rootViewInjector =
        ngModule ? createChainedInjector(injector, ngModule.injector) : injector;

    const rendererFactory =
        rootViewInjector.get(RendererFactory2, domRendererFactory3) as RendererFactory3;
    const sanitizer = rootViewInjector.get(Sanitizer, null);

    const hostRenderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, this.componentDef);
    // Determine a tag name used for creating host elements when this component is created
    // dynamically. Default to 'div' if this component did not specify any tag name in its selector.
    const elementName = this.componentDef.selectors[0][0] as string || 'div';
    const hostRNode = rootSelectorOrNode ?
        locateHostElement(hostRenderer, rootSelectorOrNode, this.componentDef.encapsulation) :
        createElementNode(
            rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, this.componentDef), elementName,
            getNamespace(elementName));

    const rootFlags = this.componentDef.onPush ? LViewFlags.Dirty | LViewFlags.IsRoot :
                                                 LViewFlags.CheckAlways | LViewFlags.IsRoot;
    const rootContext = createRootContext();

    // Create the root view. Uses empty TView and ContentTemplate.
    const rootTView = createTView(TViewType.Root, null, null, 1, 0, null, null, null, null, null);
    const rootLView = createLView(
        null, rootTView, rootContext, rootFlags, null, null, rendererFactory, hostRenderer,
        sanitizer, rootViewInjector);

    // rootView is the parent when bootstrapping
    // TODO(misko): it looks like we are entering view here but we don't really need to as
    // `renderView` does that. However as the code is written it is needed because
    // `createRootComponentView` and `createRootComponent` both read global state. Fixing those
    // issues would allow us to drop this.
    enterView(rootLView);

    let component: T;
    let tElementNode: TElementNode;

    try {
      const componentView = createRootComponentView(
          hostRNode, this.componentDef, rootLView, rendererFactory, hostRenderer);
      if (hostRNode) {
        if (rootSelectorOrNode) {
          setUpAttributes(hostRenderer, hostRNode, ['ng-version', VERSION.full]);
        } else {
          // If host element is created as a part of this function call (i.e. `rootSelectorOrNode`
          // is not defined), also apply attributes and classes extracted from component selector.
          // Extract attributes and classes from the first selector only to match VE behavior.
          const {attrs, classes} =
              extractAttrsAndClassesFromSelector(this.componentDef.selectors[0]);
          if (attrs) {
            setUpAttributes(hostRenderer, hostRNode, attrs);
          }
          if (classes && classes.length > 0) {
            writeDirectClass(hostRenderer, hostRNode, classes.join(' '));
          }
        }
      }

      tElementNode = getTNode(rootTView, HEADER_OFFSET) as TElementNode;

      if (projectableNodes !== undefined) {
        const projection: (TNode|RNode[]|null)[] = tElementNode.projection = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.ngContentSelectors.length; i++) {
          const nodesforSlot = projectableNodes[i];
          // Projectable nodes can be passed as array of arrays or an array of iterables (ngUpgrade
          // case). Here we do normalize passed data structure to be an array of arrays to avoid
          // complex checks down the line.
          // We also normalize the length of the passed in projectable nodes (to match the number of
          // <ng-container> slots defined by a component).
          projection.push(nodesforSlot != null ? Array.from(nodesforSlot) : null);
        }
      }

      // TODO: should LifecycleHooksFeature and other host features be generated by the compiler and
      // executed here?
      // Angular 5 reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/lifecycle-hooks-vcref
      component = createRootComponent(
          componentView, this.componentDef, rootLView, rootContext, [LifecycleHooksFeature]);

      renderView(rootTView, rootLView, null);
    } finally {
      leaveView();
    }

    return new ComponentRef(
        this.componentType, component, createElementRef(tElementNode, rootLView), rootLView,
        tElementNode);
  }
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: i'm going to advise against doing this. you can't create components without their selector tag, it's how angular works. removing the tags is pointless once they're already attached to the DOM as it's just extra work shuffling the tags around for no reason. if you're having performance issues, you need to render less components. IE implement some kind of virtual scrolling that only renders components when they need to be rendered

Comment: @bryan60 thank you for your prompt response. I understand why you advise against it, however, I am building custom component templates based on metadata, and the number of DOM elements created due to the issue I have is hindering the performance of the page. So, this is a problem that I have to solve. 
Thank you.

Comment: the selector tags aren't the thing causing your problem and removing them would not solve it. the problem is that you're rendering things you don't have to before you have to.  you need to fix your app so you're only rendering when you have to.